# Sequence-like Function in Scala

Tags: scala, haskell

Given a `List[Either[A,B]]`, I could use `sequence` in Haskell to extract either the entire `List` of `Right[B]`s, or `Left[A]`.

```
Prelude> sequence [Left "bad", Right 555]
Left "bad"
Prelude> sequence [Right 4534, Right 555]
Right [4534,555]
```

I'm not sure if this method fits the definition of `sequence`, but it's a narrow function for dealing with `List[Either[A,B]] => Either[A, List[B]]`.

```
scala> def f[A, B](es: List[Either[A, B]]): Either[A, List[B]] = es match {
     |   case Right(x) :: xs      => f(xs).right.map(y => x :: y)
     |   case Nil                 => Right(Nil)
     |   case left @ Left(_) :: _ => left
     | }
```

But I'm getting this error that I don't understand.

```
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[Either[?A3,?B3]] where type ?B3 <: B (this is a GADT skolem), type ?A3 <: A (this is a GADT skolem)
 required: Either[A,List[B]]
         case left @ Left(_) :: _ => left
                                     ^
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

The error message is saying that the type of `left` is `Either[A, B]` but the expected type of `f` is `Either[A, List[B]]`.

You'll need to deconstruct Left in the case and then reconstruct it in the expression. It seems silly but you have the remember that the `Left(x)` in the branch is tagged with a different type from the one you want.

```
| case Left(x) :: _ => Left(x)
```

Haskell would give you a similar error:

```
f :: Either a b -> Either a [b]
f l@(Left x) = l

Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘[b]’
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for f :: Either a b -> Either a [b]
      at /Users/Jake/Code/Haskell/L.hs:3:6
Expected type: Either a [b]
  Actual type: Either a b
Relevant bindings include
  l :: Either a b (bound at /Users/Jake/Code/Haskell/L.hs:4:3)
  f :: Either a b -> Either a [b]
    (bound at /Users/Jake/Code/Haskell/L.hs:4:1)
In the expression: l
In an equation for ‘f’: f l@(Left x) = l
```